# unable to import library project in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have modified library project of finestwebview [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2DWplz9UCJjaW9BeWxtLXFYNE0/view?pref=2&pli=1)

I tried to add this library project in to my android studio's project but I got several errors saying **configuration with name 'default' not found** android studio.need help. I wasted my 1 whole days trying this but unable to add.

what I tried is

I copied the library project into the libs folder of my root project,and added **'include:libs:finestwebview'** in setting.gradle file.

Also going to

file->project structure->app->dependencies

added the module and sync the project but cannot achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including a project, so for that you should add it as a module, and say compile project in your app's gradle dependencies to use it in your app module.

go to 
File->New->Import module and add your library project folder

you will have to name your library project there 
then you need to say

```
`compile project(':yourlibraryProjectname')`
```

in your gradle dependency